# It doesn't recognize a file within an imported file

Tags: javascript, react-native, import, frontend, navigation-drawer

I have created a MenuButton as well as 2 other pages one of them being the settingScreen, where I have imported the MenuButton within both files and they seem to be working fine. But when I import the setting Screen on the DrawerNavigator file it doesn't recognize MenuButton

```
Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(Unable to resolve module `./Menu/MenuButton` from `/Users/camillebasbous/Project/Menu/SettingScreen.js`: The module `./Menu/MenuButton` could not be found from `/Users/camillebasbous/Project/Menu/SettingScreen.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
  * `/Users/camillebasbous/Project/Menu/Menu/MenuButton(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
  * `/Users/camillebasbous/Project/Menu/Menu/MenuButton/index(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)` (null))

__38-[RCTCxxBridge loadSource:onProgress:]_block_invoke.228
    RCTCxxBridge.mm:414
___ZL36attemptAsynchronousLoadOfBundleAtURLP5NSURLU13block_pointerFvP18RCTLoadingProgressEU13block_pointerFvP7NSErrorP9RCTSourceE_block_invoke.118
__80-[RCTMultipartDataTask URLSession:streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:]_block_invoke
-[RCTMultipartStreamReader emitChunk:headers:callback:done:]
-[RCTMultipartStreamReader readAllPartsWithCompletionCallback:progressCallback:]
-[RCTMultipartDataTask URLSession:streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:]
__88-[NSURLSession delegate_streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:completionHandler:]_block_invoke
__NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
-[NSBlockOperation main]
-[__NSOperationInternal _start:]
__NSOQSchedule_f
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_continuation_pop
_dispatch_async_redirect_invoke
_dispatch_root_queue_drain
_dispatch_worker_thread2
_pthread_wqthread
start_wqthread
```

I have tried testing ou the other page and after a few tests I realized that the presence of the imported MenuButton within these pages is what is forcing an error Is there a way to import a file that has imported another to be displayed or do I have to import both of them within drawerNavigation and if so how to structure the code. Thanks

Drawer Navigation code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
  DrawerItems,
  SafeAreaView,
} from 'react-navigation';
import SettingScreen from './Menu/SettingScreen'





class Home extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <SettingScreen/>

      </View>
    );
  }
}



const Navigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home,

  },
  {
    //drawerType: 'back',
    // drawerPosition: 'right',
    // drawerWidth: 200,
  drawerBackgroundColor: '#262A2C',
    // contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent
  }
);

 export default createAppContainer(Navigator);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',

  }
});
```

SettingScreen code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import MenuButton from './Menu/MenuButton'

export default class SettingScreen extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <MenuButton/>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Settings</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(215,215,215,1)',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
text:{
    fontSize: 30,
    }
});
```

MenuButton code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, View} from "react-native" ;
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen'



export default class MenuButton extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(

        <View >

        <Icon name= "ios-menu" size={wp('12%')} color='#9B9B9B' style={{position: 'absolute', top: wp('-82.5%'), left: wp('-46%'), }}></Icon>

                 </View>
        ) 
    }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('Menu', () => FixedDimensionsBasics);
```

Comment: The issue seems to be with your import path. Can you describe how these files are organized in your folders?

Comment: @ViniciusCleves sure /Users/camillebasbous/project/Menu/SettingScreen /Users/camillebasbous/project/Menu/MenuButton /Users/camillebasbous/project/Menu/Map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you are using on import is relative to your file. So, as everything is on the same folder, you must correct the import path like that:

1. On Drawer Navigator code

   ```
   import SettingScreen from './SettingScreen'
   ```
2. On SettingScreen code

   ```
   import MenuButton from './MenuButton'
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out when I'm done with what I am doing and get back to you on it